# How to control Video Cam connected to Firewire using a program

Tags: .net, video, firewire

I need to control (play,rewind,stop) my Video Cam  connected to firewire of my PC
Is this possible. My program is written in .NET

Thanks
Anon

Answer (score 2):

This is done through DirectShow which is part of the Windows SDK. Take a look at the [DVApp sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms783409(VS.85).aspx).